# System.SObjectException help me to resolve this Exception?

Tags: apex, trigger

### This is my query :

```
List<Integration__c> listAll = [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,IntegrationAccount__c FROM Integration__c ];
```

### this is my code :

```
List<Case> cas = Trigger.new;

List<Integration__c> listAll = [SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,IntegrationAccount__c,integrationwith__c FROM Integration__c ];

for(Case c : cas  )
{
    for(Integration__c intObj:listAll)
    {
        if(intObj.IntegrationAccount__r.name.contains(c.Account.name)){

            String name = intObj.username__c;
            String pwd = intObj.password__c;
            String url = intObj.URL__c;
     }
  }
}
```

This code doesn't cause for any compile time errors but when creating a new case in case details page shows the  exception

### Exception:

> Execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: SObject
>   row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field:
>   Integration__c.IntegrationAccount__r: Trigger.Type: line 26, column 1

Comment: Just add `IntegrationAccount__r.Name` into your query on `Integration__c`...

Comment: i changed like as you said but when creating a case again it occurs new exception:    Apex trigger Type caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Type: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.: Trigger.Type: line 26, column 1

Comment: The error messages are pretty descriptive are you having trouble understanding them? Did you put any effort at all into a simple google search? They are common and well documented with a 5 second search  also lots of duplicate questions on this site

Comment: `IntegrationAccount__r` lookup is not populated on that record... Check for nulls...

Comment: Note that if you are using email2case, not all Cases will have a populated value for `Case.AccountId` - this will affect your trigger

Answer (score 2):

You are not querying the relationship `IntegrationAccount__r.name`  but you tried to access it inside the for loop.

so you should add it in your query, like this.

`SELECT id,name,username__c,password__c,URL__c,IntegrationAccount__c,IntegrationAccount__r.name, integrationwith__c FROM Integration__c`